# how to make default.png to rotate as per device orientation in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How to rotate the Default.png in cocos2d as per device orientation. I heard that we have to put 2 files Default-LandscapeLeft.png and Default-LandscapeRight.png in resource folder and remove default.png. How to make it viewable in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Cocos2d thing especifically. You just have to add the 4 default.png images to your porject's resource folder.
Check this post: http://iosdevelopertips.com/ipad/ipad-managing-multiple-launch-images.html

Comment: Note: The extra orientation options are only supported on iPad, not iPhone/ipod.  Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't worry about this too much, as no one is going to judge your app on how well it autorotates for the 2 seconds the default screen is showing.  Anyways, I second what pabloruiz55 said.

Comment: Whoever down voted this, could they kindly explain why they did that.